# WPF - Dynamically instantiating a ViewModel for an item in the Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two models - one the 'Field' and other, the 'Layout' which in turn is a collection of Field. I use these to implement a tree structure. I am trying to avoid implementing a ViewModel for the Layout simply to avoid having to navigate to each node on the tree and to avoid another indirection for pushing background updates. But I have to create a ViewModel for the items (Field) in the collection. Is that possible without breaking the MVVM pattern?

I was actually thinking of something like an extension properties on the 'Field' which I can use for binding in the View but after a bit of analysis found [that is not possible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/05/why-no-extension-properties.aspx). Is there any other technique that could be used in this scenario?

```
// Model
public interface IField
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
}

public interface ILayout : ICollection<IField>, IField
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a view model for each type of data. Instead, you can simply implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on them. In my opinion, each view model should have a view, so you would need one view model that contains the collection of objects to be displayed in the `TreeView`. The standard way to define a class like this would be like this:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    public string Type { get; set; } // correctly on all of these properties   
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then your view model would have at least an `ObservableCollection<Item> Items` property to `Bind` with the `TreeView.ItemsSource` property.